# syncronized block doens't block different objects

Tags: java, multithreading

i inserted in an hashMap (for each row) this:

```
rows.put(currentRow, new Object());
....
```

and after some threads will call this function:

```
   @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            increaseRow(new Random().nextInt(10));
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }

public  void increaseRow(Integer row) {
        synchronized (rows.get(row)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                matrix[row][j] += 1;
            }
            System.out.println("begin print");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("end print");
        }
   }
```

if i start 1 thread, it works ok, but there are some problems with more threads, like:

```
begin print
00000
begin print
00
0000000000000000
00
000000000000000000000
00000000000
00000000000000
00000000000
00
000000000000
111111111111
000000000000
111000000000000
000000000000
111111111111
000000000000
111111111111
000000000000
0000000100000
end print
```

the map as only 10 key-value , i' m syncronizing on the object value, so i don't understand what's wrong.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem?

Comment: well the problem is why the print is not syncronized?

Comment: Synchronization works based on each actual object, not on the value. That is, it works on `==` not `.equals`, though this can be a bit confusing with autoboxing. So if you have `foo != bar` but `foo.equals(bar)`, then `synchronized (foo) {...}` and `synchronized (bar) {...}` will _not_ affect each other.

Comment: They're presumably synchronized on different objects.

Comment: You're calling `increaseRow(..)` with different values from 0-9. You said the `rows` map contains a mapping for each of those values with a different object for each.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis exaclty, so the print, must be syncronized..

Comment: It's synchronized for different rows. If a thread is acting on row 3, then no other thread can call the method for row 3. But if one thread is doing row 5 and another is doing row 8, then they won't block eachother.

Comment: ok, now i understood.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if i add a monitor on the print, this will be syncronized for the current row, for example, i T1 enter with row 2 and T2 enter with row 5, a print monitor will sync with row2 until i finish right? So it's no a good solution

Comment: Do you want all print statements to occur in a transactional batch?

Comment: Then you need all threads to synchronize on the same object around that critical section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force it to only print 'begin print' then 'end print' for each row update (not interleaved) you would need to synchronize on the 'rows' object.

While only 1 thread at a time can write to the rows.get(0) object , you can still get a lock on rows.get(0) and rows.get(1) and rows.get(2) objects concurrently. This means your output can contain 'begin print' multiple times in a row followed by multiple 'end print' lines.

Depending on what you're attempting to achieve here - I would simply output the row you're updating since you know that two can be done at once - synch only the row you wish.

```
public  void increaseRow(Integer row) {
    synchronized (rows.get(row)) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            matrix[row][j] += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("begin update row %s", row));
        for (int i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                System.out.print(String.format("row %s value %s",row,matrix[i][j]));
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("String.format("end update row %s", row)");
    }
```

}

or if you just want each thread to tell you what row it updated:

```
    public  void increaseRow(Integer row) {
        synchronized (rows.get(row)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                matrix[row][j] += 1;
                System.out.print(String.format("row %s value %s",row,matrix[row][j]));
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: OP seemed to want all printing to happen as a batch.

Comment: I don't think this fixes anything unless print is synchronized, and in that case you are back to a "global" lock

Comment: Most (if not all) implementations of the JVM synchronize println(*) functions, at least since Java 1.1 or so - no need to resynch and the only time there is a global lock in place is during the actual operation of writing to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The printing gets scrambled because you synchronize access on the same row. So the updates for two different rows may interleave. Which is probably fine, except that the printing looks garbled.

To synchronize the printing (there are multiple rows you can update in parallel, but there is only one screen), do something like this:

```
public  void increaseRow(Integer row) {
  synchronized (rows.get(row)) {
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      matrix[row][j] += 1;
    }

    // Printing here makes sense for debugging only

    synchronized (rows) (
      System.out.println("begin print");
      for (int i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
          System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("end print");
    }
  }
}
```

Btw: Why use a hash map for the row locks instead of just an array?

Comment: i can't syncronize on the same row, because for example, if a take the lock for row1 with thread1, another thread that want row1 can't so, this is not the problem.

Comment: The synchronization for the update is fine, but if you want to avoid the prints to overlap, you need to sync on something more global

Comment: thanks for the snippet, can you explain me the nested lock on the map?

Comment: hmm this forces a block on rows every time you update row(x) - basically while you are updating each row concurrently you're forcing your threads to wait on each other while they print. You're better off with my answer below which allows all rows to be updated concurrently and printed to console concurrently without blocking except on concurrent updates to the same row.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. So the threads remains in waiting before `synchronized (rows)` until they can print.

Comment: Yokupoku - all the threads update the value concurrently(and in any order) then whoever gets to print first locks the entire table, then prints - the others wait in line and print after, no thread that is waiting to print can update a row until it has printed. i.e. you'll get one print per thread, per update.

Comment: @ChrisKannon You have to block for print to avoid garbling the text unless print is synchronized internally, which then would just have the same effect (other row updates are blocked). Note that as many row updates as you have threads still can take place in parallel before they are blocked. Multi-threading an operation which uses the same IO resource may just not make that much sense in the first place.