# synchronize on multiple objects

Tags: java, multithreading

In a previous question -> [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490567/syncronized-block-doenst-block-different-objects)  i received a good solution (which works) to resolve my issue.
But i haven't understand how exactly works.

So if i have many threads that can enter concurrently on this synchronized block, and according to the java docs this code is:

```
synchronized(...){
   //atomic for the operation inside 
}
```

So, i' m asking:

why this operation is atomic:

```
for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    matrix[row][j] += 1;
                }
```

and not this one:

```
       System.out.println("begin print");
         for (int i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
             System.out.println();
             for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                 System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
          }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("end print");
```

my full function is this:

```
public  void increaseRow(Integer row) {
        synchronized (rows.get(row)) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                matrix[row][j] += 1;
            }
            System.out.println("begin print");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.row; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                    System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("end print");
        }
   }
```

Could someone provide me a useful explanation, i'll appreciate a lot.

Comment: I think that you will find that it is atomic, however the print spool is not.  If you had some global incrementing counter, I think that you would find that they are in order.

Comment: Printing is traditionally slow and is being written to by a multiple of threads - not a good idea to make in atomic I think

Comment: Essentially, will be slow also the incrementing part inside the block, and why it is syncronized?

Comment: It is not atomic. It is mutually exclusive. That is two different things No threads can pass through a synchronized block unless it does not hold the the monitor itself. In this case the monitor is the object in the hashmap. So it is excluded mutually (wrt to the monitor only). Atomic means as one single operation, and while it may be perceived as one, clearly each operation may affect state in other objects that permeates outside of the context.

Comment: Ok i understand what you said, but if T1 and T2 enter this block with two different rows to compute, the print will be also sync..

Comment: T1 holds lock on row 1, T2 holds lock on row 2. Not synchronized.. T1 holds lock on row 1, T2 tries to get lock on row 1. Synchronized...

Comment: When you synchronize you would most likely use huidubes idiom below and not on the row object.

Comment: Additionally, keep in mind that the standard Synchronised does not guarantee order. The lock is released to a random pending thread! To achieve this you will need a Reentrant Lock ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html )

Comment: i read that the syncronized keyword is the as the lock of concurrent api , is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's stated in comment, System.out.println is not thread safe operation.

The problem is the way you lock your critical section.

```
  synchronized (rows.get(row)) { }
```

This code means, that you are locking on specific row, not the whole table, so **if you have N rows, that means N locks exist** at the same time, and there fore N threads can run simultaneously populating System.out in parallel.

Locking on a row gives you a better parallelism: Thread working on row 2, can work at the same time, as Thread working on row 3.

Another option is to have a single lock for the whole table section.

```
Object lock = new Object();
...
public void someMethod(){
    synchronized(lock){...}
}
```

In this case there is only one lock, and only one Thread executing it at the same time, so you are effectively calling your System.out synchronously from your code.

Locking on a table, decreases parallelism, since you decrease number of locks, available: Thread working on row 2, would need to wait for Thread working on row 3, to release the lock.

Thread safety, that synchronous guaranties affects only functions, written in the block, not externally called functions, it does not make System.out atomic operation.

Comment: +1 for the system.out explanation. But i need to keep the work in parallel, so i can' t instantiate a global lock.

Comment: That means, you'll have to deal with System.out pollution, which is a normal case :)

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use your class object: `synchronized(this)`
or, even more secure:  `synchronized(YourClassName.class)`
or some other lock?

```
Object lock = new Object();
...
public void someMethod(){
    synchronized(lock){...}
}
```

> Every Java object created, including every Class loaded, has an associated lock or monitor. Putting code inside a synchronized block makes the compiler append instructions to acquire the lock on the specified object before executing the code, and release it afterwards (either because the code finishes normally or abnormally). Between acquiring the lock and releasing it, a thread is said to "own" the lock. At the point of Thread A wanting to acquire the lock, if Thread B already owns the it, then Thread A must wait for Thread B to release it.
>   (http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_synchronized1.shtml)

but if your lock changes, while a thread uses this lock in a synchronized block, it can occure that another block can enter the synchronized block with this changed lock.
Example:

```
Object lock = new Object();
int value = 0;

public void increment(){
    synchronized(lock){value++;}
}

public void printValue(){
    synchronized(lock){System.out.println(value);}
}
```

timeline:

thread1:
calling printValue() //taking the lock
thread2:
lock = new Object(); //the lock changes, its another object now
calling increment()  //taking this new lock. the old lock is still reserved by thread1
value is getting incrementing.
threat1:
printing the wrong value.

EDIT: Didn't see that he needs a lock for each row.

Comment: That actually, would change the meaning of the function :) Although, this is most likely what is needed.

Comment: each thread can enter with different rows, so block the eniter object monitor is not a solution. -1 , but i can't downvote.

Comment: See my answer, I guess I was not clear here. Keeping single lock would decrease performance and parallelism, if you only ever need to lock on a row.

Comment: What is it you want to synchronize. The printout or the handling of the row. If indeed you look at the printout, then you need a single lock.. That is not a table/row lock debate, that is a printaccess debate.

Comment: ah, i see. well, as long as there is no operation changing the rows, this lock should be fine.

Comment: well the operations on the table WORKS PRETTY WELL. as @NielsBechNielsen said the print is slow, so it's needed further actions.

Comment: well, if you write everything into a String object and print afterwards, the single printout lines are not mixed with the output of the other threads. but the order of the printouts is still random. you could also write a synchronized printout method.